# String to comma separated array using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an input string like

```
[{"brand_id":"112"},{"brand_id":"114"},{"brand_id":"14"}]
```

and I want to convert the string to a format like this using Newtonsoft.

```
[112,114,14]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse input string to JArray, then use [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) to get value of particular key(in Your case it is `brand_id`)

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
//Input string 
string json = @"[{'brand_id':'112'},{'brand_id':'114'},{'brand_id':'14'}]"; 
//Convert input string to JArray
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
//Select only specific field
var brandIds = jArray.Select(x => x["brand_id"]);
```

---

[Try online: C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2rCIMC)

---

If you already have model defined for the input string, then you can use `DeserializeObject()` method which is explained by @YongShun

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve with `DeserializeObject` to `List<Brand>`. And use `.Select()` to get `brand_id` only.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

string json = "[{\"brand_id\":\"112\"},{\"brand_id\":\"114\"},{\"brand_id\":\"14\"}]";
List<Brand> brands = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Brand>>(json);
List<string> brandIDs = brands.Select(x => x.Brand_Id).ToList();
```

```cs
public class Brand
{
    [JsonProperty("brand_id")]
    public string Brand_Id {get;set;}   
}
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EV985e)

Comment: Deserialize is a bit slow ;)

Comment: @zolty13 use `System.Text.Json` then, it's rather faster.

Comment: I means that using JArray is faster than deserializing